# PHP XMLRPC Error - cannot serialize xmlrpcresp objects whose content is native php values

Tags: php, xml-rpc, payload

I have a PHP xmlrpc-client (http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/) calling a remote PHP xmlrpc-server. Most of the time it works but sometimes it fails with,

**Invalid return payload: enable debugging to examine incoming payload (XML error at line 1, check URL).**

On enabling debug, I got the error info as,

```
<PRE>---GOT---

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 07 Dec 2011 03:39:02 GMT

Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3

Vary: Accept-Encoding

Content-Encoding: gzip

Content-Length: 266

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html
```

.

.

```
cannot serialize xmlrpcresp objects whose content is native php values.
```

The content type is shown as html instead of xml, is this the issue ?. I would like to get some help to proceed further.

Comment: Awesome.  I get the same thing.  http://xkcd.com/979/